# Mysql: Select distinct, same column names from different tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have searched for a similar problem but am unable to find what I'm after.
I have 2 tables:

```
|-------ITEMS--------|    |------PEOPLE--------|
|   id    |   name   |    |   id    |   name   |
|--------------------|    |--------------------| 
|   1     |   item1  |    |   1     | person1  |
|   2     |   item2  |    |   2     | person2  |
|   3     |   item3  |    |--------------------|    
|   4     |   item4  |    
|   5     |   item5  |
|--------------------|
```

I need a single query that will return the following:

```
|--------------------|  
|  items  |  people  |  
|--------------------|  
| item1   | person1  |  
| item2   | person2  |  
| item3   |          |  
| item4   |          |    
| item5   |          |
|--------------------|
```

How can such a query be constructed please?

Comment: It's a meaningless result - what if the people ids were 1 and 3? Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: Why would. you align item ids and people ids?  They are different things.

Answer (score 0):

@AllenS You need to use a `LEFT JOIN` like this:

```
SELECT `i`.`name` AS `items`,
    `p`.`name` AS `people`
FROM `ITEMS` AS `i`
LEFT JOIN `PEOPLE` AS `p` ON `p`.`id` = `i`.`id`
```

[Here are your tables and the answer mocked up on db-fiddle.](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cCnUXQA19a2pE53xfuU6p7/0)

If this doesn't get you what you need please let me know and I'll try to assist further.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, your intention is to line up two tables in two different columns.  This is not a very "SQL" thing to do, but you can do so using `row_number()` and aggregation:

```
select max(item) as item, max(person) as person
from ((select i.name as item, null as person, row_number() over (partition by id) as seqnum
       from items i
      ) union all
      (select null, p.name, row_number() over (partition by id) as seqnum
       from people p
      )
     ) ip
group by seqnum
```